# Java | Бинарная матрица

Tags: java

Дан план замка,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

который представлен в виде матрицы типа String:

```
1111 1110 1101 0110 1100 0101 0110 
1110 1001 0110 1011 1010 1111 1010 
1000 0101 0011 1110 1011 1110 1010 
1011 1101 0101 0001 0101 0011 1011
```

Каждый элемент матрицы - это двоичное число в 4-битном представлении. Оно представляет собой стороны каждой ячейки, рассматриваемые в следующем порядке: слева - вверх - справа - вниз. Чёрным жирным цветом выделены стены ("1", если есть стена, а "0", если нет). Нужно вычислить количество комнат замка (их 5), определить координаты левого верхнего угла каждой комнаты (1 ↔ [1,1] ; 2 ↔ [4,2]; 3 ↔[1,3]; 4 ↔ [1,5]; 5 ↔ [2,6]) и количество квадратиков, которые принадлежат каждой комнате (например, для первой комнаты с координатами левого верхнего угла [1, 1] 9 квадратиков). Для получения стены можно использовать matrix[i][j].charAt(0) = '1'. Это значит, что мы смотрим, если ли на нулевой позиции (слева) стена. Как это сделать в коде? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

-создайте пустой список, в котором будете хранить пройденные квадратики

-создайте пустой список, в котором будете хранить левый верхний угол

-создайте пустой список, в котором будете хранить кол-во квадратиков в комнате

-создайте функцию типа int, которая принимает на вход координаты текущего квадратика и значение ее стен. создайте переменную int со значением 1, которая будет возвращать кол-во пройденных функцией квадратиков. в цикле пройдитесь по значением стен квадратика, если стены нет, то вызывается функция с координатами квадратика, в который она ведет, возвращаемое значение функции добавляется к созданной переменной. функция возвращает ее

-в цикле начинаете прохождение по матрице: если ячейка не пройдена, то она добавляется в список с левыми верхними углами. вызываете созданную ранее функцию, ее значение добавляете в список с кол-вом квадратиков в комнате

также можете почитать про задачи на графы